# Add images to jupyter notebooks viewable through github in a private repo

Tags: image, github, jupyter

I found that images embedded in jupyter markups by a simple eg `![](img/myimage.png)` didnt display in the github notebook viewer, when the repository is private.

I tried a bunch of hacking around.

Apparently there is functionality in 4.x.x to embed images as base64 metadata?  But I couldnt see that in my own notebook.

Answer (score 9):

Finally, what worked for me, very simply, create a code cell that looks like:

```
from IPython.display import Image, display
display(Image(filename='img/myimage.png', embed=True))
```

This did:

- loaded the local image `img/myimage.png`, into the notebook
- embedded it in the notebook (probably as base64), so that it could be viewed via the github notebook viewer, with no issues
- didnt involve embedding 400 lines of base64 into the `code` section itself :-)

Comment: Works for me, but ugly as hell since the rendered page shows not only the figure but also the two-line code snippet

Comment: super nice hack! Do you know if something similar is available for gifs?