# Image in Jupyter Notebook ipynb doesn't show up in GitHub private repo but the same code works with public repo

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I have a Jupyter Notebook `.ipynb` file in my GitHub repository. It is supposed to show an image via the following markdown code:

```
![image](image.png)
```

The image does show up when the repository is public. However, when the repository is set to private, only the alternative caption "image" is visible and the image doesn't load. If I right-click on it and select "View Image", the image loads fine.

The issue also doesn't exist for `.md` Markdown files: the same line above works for public and private repos.

There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42159315) which describes how to *embed* images into the `.ipynb` file, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to display the `.png` file dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2015, [Jupyter notebooks are rendered on GitHub using nbviewer](https://blog.jupyter.org/rendering-notebooks-on-github-f7ac8736d686). From this blog post they state:

> Second, because of security concerns, some features available on nbviewer will not be available on GitHub. For example, GitHub will not render any dynamic output display that uses JavaScript, custom CSS, and most custom HTML embedded in Markdown or in outputs. When this is the case, and GitHub cannot fully render your notebooks, you will see an icon that allows you to view the full notebook on nbviewer.

An [issue thread](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3035) has some users saying that logging out/logging in will resolve the issue. Others say it is resolved over time. But there seems to be no recognized solution.

Answer (score 1):

When I made my repo public, Github required me to confirm my credentials, but as soon as it was public, the images rendered. It could have been either so I'd suggest either logging out / in or making your repo public (then taking immediately private again if need be).

Comment: This method works for me. I didn't change anything in my code. As soon as my repo goes public, images in the jupyter notebook are displayed rightly.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot, than at last was able to fix it.

1. Use "/" instead of "\" in image path

[image]

2. If you are using width field for png image file than .png should be small, width="200" number should be in quotes, img should be closed like this ->img src="Image/neuron-1.png" width="300" />

Answer (score 0):

I have tested most of the comments; however, only the following works for me:

1. Build the folder in the same repository with the image name.
2. Create a file `.gitkeep` in the Image folder.
3. Upload your images in this folder.
4. Add address like: `<img src='Image/name.PNG' />`
5. Note: building Image folder is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

## Paste Image From Clipboard Into Markdown Cell

I found out that I only needed to do a simple copy an image `Ctrl + C` and then paste into markdown cell with `Ctrl + V`.

The link to an image should look something like this:

```markdown
![image.png](attachment:image.png)
```

Only then the image became visible in my private repo! Something like the following **DID NOT WORK** for me:

```markdown
![](images/sample-image.png)
```

Comment: Drag-and-drop should also work for getting the image into the markdown as an attachment. In your example that didn't work, that is the style for writing it in text and pointing at an external file using a relative path. In this case there'd be expected to be a directory named 'images' in the same directory as the notebook with that markdown in it and then inside the directory 'images' is the file 'sample-image.png'. So when rendered it will look for the image file along that relative path. The file hierarchy and other directories need to be maintained to keep rendering working.

Comment: <continued> In other words, you need to signal to Jupyter how you are going to manage the related images. If you copy or drag them in, then you indicate you want them as attachments (**that also get encoded as base64 code in the notebook file**) or if you use the relative path, you are going to manage the notebook and associated directories and files yourself. With many images, the attachments approach can become unwieldy as it adds substantially to the size of the `.ipynb` file. Note my comments don't get at why inside a private repo, the relative path approach wouldn't work, in part ...

Comment: <continued> because I haven't worked in private repos enough to go looking at why this is. But I don't see anyone else really addressing that anyways? I would guess because higher security, the relative path isn't accessible from the notebook file? Using the attachment approach, the image code gets embedded  and so it isn't an issue. Anyway, all these extended comments were meant to put in context what is going on with each of those two approaches of adding an image in a Jupyter notebook involving markdown syntax (and no HTML) for those curious or maybe new to the Jupyter ecosystem.